# Changing the GPS coordinates with out moving anywhere

Tags: android

> ****i have used the gps coordinates for calculating the distance using location updates. but problem is that if i am standing at same place the coordinates changes and distance is changing with out moving anywhere. I want to change it only when I have moved min 10 mtrs.

```
## Activity ##

//Activity

public TextView dist;
public double lati1,lati2,longi1,longi2;
private boolean run1 = false; 
private Handler handler1 = new Handler();
private Runnable task1 = new Runnable() {

     public void run() {  
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        if (run1) {  
            handler1.postDelayed(this,1000);  
            if(lati1==0.0&&longi1==0.0)
            {
                    lati1=Service1.lat1;
                        longi1=Service1.lon1;
            }

                        lati2=Service1.lat1;
                        longi2=Service1.lon1;

              double R=63710;
              double dLat=Math.toRadians(lati2-lati1);
              double dLon=Math.toRadians(longi2-longi1);

                       double a=Math.sin(dLat/2)*Math.sin(dLat/2)+
                       Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lati1))*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lati2))*
             Math.sin(dLon/2)*Math.sin(dLon/2);

             double c=2*Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
             double d=R*c;
             d=(double)(Math.round(d*100.00))/1000.00;
             distance+=d;
             String s=String.format("%.2f", distance);
             dist.setText(s); 

             lati1 = lati2;
             longi1 = longi2;

                    } 



            }  
        };
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

        dist=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.distancetextView);
          Intent i =  new Intent(context, Service1.class);

        startService(i);

}







## Service ##


//Service



private double new_latitude = 0.0;
private double new_longitude = 0.0;

public static double lat1=0.0,lon1=0.0;

LocationManager locationManager = null;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0L, 0.0f, this);
super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onStart(intent, startId);
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
super.onDestroy();
}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

new_latitude=location.getLatitude();
new_longitude=location.getLongitude();


lat1=new_latitude;
lon1=new_longitude;
}

public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}****
```

Comment: Make a filter to the receiver of the locationChanged event. After you count the distance, ignore results smaller than 10m.

Comment: @Gjordis:-Thank you for your replay, but in my application i am calculating the distance based on frequent locations  for every second. when i am moving from one location to the other location with out stop moving , it is showing correct distance. but here the problem is, if i want to wait any where like traffic signals, at that time also it's calculating the distance. i have added my code above. please help. thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use GPS speed to determine if you are moving. Comparing two consecutive GPS speed values would give more reliable results than checking just one. Since when the coordinates "vibrate" according to GPS-signal quality, while standing still, the GPS speed also might show something. But comparing two values reduces this "static". But this does not compeltely remove the problem.  SportsTracker for example suffers from this same issue,

Comment: @Gjordis:- can you please help me how to write the code for GPS speed and comparing two consecutive GPS speed values?

Answer (score 0):

I should see the code you are writing. But without it I can say that there is a function, that you call, and it give you location update each X milliseconds. Or you can get the latest updated location, again, I should see your code.

UPDATE:

change this line

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0L, 0.0f, this);
```

to

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0L, 10.0f, this);
```

You'll receive updates after moving 10m.

The second parameter is time in millisecond, the third is minimum distance. But it doesn't mean you'll get update exactly at the requested time or requested distance, but rather about it.

Comment: @SajjadHeydari- just now i tried it on my device, but it shows the distance 1.71 km  with in 5 min and with out moving anywhere. what i want is ,it has to calculate the distance when i am moving only, stop the calculation when i am not moving.

Comment: That's perhaps because you used last known location, which I think was used 1.71km away. You can ask for update when a button is pressed.

Comment: Runnable is working after the i press the button. So, the updates also  happening after i press the button.

Comment: Is there any use with Location Strategies. then,how can we use the Location Strategies.

Answer (score 0):

//Public or class variable of previous speed initialised on class.
  // float previousSpeed;

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   new_latitude=location.getLatitude();
   new_longitude=location.getLongitude();

   float speed = location.getSpeed();
   //You could also use location.hasSpeed(), which is a boolean, but it almost 
   //always returns True

   if(speed > DESIRED_LIMIT && previousSpeed > DESIRED_LIMIT){

      lat1=new_latitude;
      lon1=new_longitude;

   }

   previousSpeed = speed;
}
```

So something like that. That condition is not very well optimized or designed. But that is how you get GPS speed from location object. You can tweak the speed limit or the whole condition to get the best results. Or add even more history of speed to monitor.

Comment: Considering what you want, Sajjiad's answer might be better, but when moving at slow speeds, the absolute limit of 10m difference to previous location might limit the amount of updates you get. I think his answer might be easier to implement

Comment: Still i am facing the same problem.

Comment: Is there any use with Location Strategies on my code. then,how can we use the Location Strategies.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the location spoofer application from the android market and specify the duration of spoofing the location and also the distance